# Python renaming a file using contents from within the file for all files of that file type in working directory

Tags: python, html

```
# Import tools used in code - lxml is not a normal library
# The .whl file will need to be downloaded and added - use PIP to install .whl files
import os, gc, shutil, re, xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
# GC is garbage collector
gc.collect()
from lxml import etree
# Read through directory  pulling in filenames
# This currently needs to be modified to match folder structure - will retool to work from anywhere to anywhere
for fileCDR in os.listdir("Absolute File Path"):
    # Check files looking for .cdr
    if fileCDR.endswith(".cdr"):
        # Parse file into string to pull out XML Flags - Try Exception used was having issues with tools
        # Need to remove one of them as they are both not needed
        try:
                pfile = etree.parse(fileCDR).getroot()
        except:
                pfile = ET.parse(fileCDR).getroot()
        # print (file)
        # Read through xml in pfile variable - looking for start time
        for startTime in pfile.findall('XML Tag startTime'):
            start = startTime.text.replace(':', '-')
        # Read through xml in pfile variable looking for Dialed Digits - originalDestinationId   
        for originalDestinationId in pfile.findall('XML Tag originalDestinationId'):
            number = originalDestinationId.text
        # Read through xml in pfile variable - looking for filename - correlationId    
        for correlationId in pfile.findall('XML Tag correlationId'):
            fileName = correlationId.text
        # Store all the collected variables into one variable to rename .cdr files
        cdrDone = (start + "_" + number + "_" + fileName + ".cdr")
        # Store all the collected variables into one variable to rename .ogg files
        new_fileName = (start + "_" + number + "_" + fileName + ".ogg")
        # Store file name of .cdr file to use in if statement to match files up
        compareFile = fileCDR[:-4]
        # Read through directory pulling in filenames
        for fileOGG in os.listdir("Absolute File Path"):
            # Used to check if filename ends in .ogg
            if fileOGG.endswith(".ogg"):
                # Used to trim file name of .ogg to match .cdr file
                compareFileName = fileOGG[:-4]  # type: string
                # Used to make sure filenames match - .cdr and .ogg
                if compareFileName == compareFile:
                # These all currently needs to be modified to match folder structure - will retool to work from anywhere to anywhere
                    oggFile = os.path.join("Absolute File Path", fileOGG)
                    newOGG = os.path.join("Absolute File Path", new_fileName)
                    shutil.move(oggFile, newOGG)
                    cdrFile = os.path.join("Absolute File Path", fileCDR)
                    newCDR = ("Absolute File Path", cdrDone)
                    shutil.move(cdrFile, newCDR)
                    print (newOGG + " " + newCDR)
```

Originally I needed help reading in file names from a directory. I was able to find my answers but had more questions. The files I was trying to identify in a folder structure had xml inside them. After identifying those files I needed a way to parse out metadata in the xml. After pulling out the metadata from the xml I needed to save a file that shared the same name but had a different file extension. I wanted to retain the filename and include the two flags I wanted from the xml. I wanted the files moved outside of the source folder into a new folder while doing the renaming. This is the end result and contains the answer to my question in addition to a few other hurdles I had. I appreciate peoples feedback and am aware my question and original request was no good. It was my first time making a post on this site. Thanks again and hopefully this helps someone else out.

P.S. This is my first Python program and I want to do more with it. If I did things that could be modified for efficiency I would appreciate the tips or pointers.

Comment: Kind of hard to answer your question without your code and specifics on the problem you're running into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

load this up in a DOM and extract the value of the node you want.
save that value in a variable. *close the file you want to rename* . use the value stored in the variable to rename the file.

sorry, it is just pseudo-code but all the steps are well documented in many places.